# How to show MKAnnotationView in a center of MKPolygon while zoom In/out?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, mkmapview

[image: Zoom in]

[image: Zoom out]

Please share your valuable comments.

Comment: Its completely game of Your Image, or you can make a change in its `AnchorPoint` property.

Comment: thanks Mrug, tried using AnchorPoint before , but not showing result as expected.